# PHP Mysql PDO retrieve records by date range

Tags: mysql, pdo, php-7, mysql-5.6

I'm retrieving a list of items from my database using the PDO approach and when I do:

```php
$select['from'] = date('Y-m-d 00:00:00',strtotime("2016-02-01"));
$sql = "SELECT * FROM listings WHERE date_added >= :date AND date_added < DATE_ADD(:date, INTERVAL 30 DAY)";
$statement = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$statement->bindParam(":date", $select['from'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$statement->execute();
```

var_dump of my result gives:

```
object(stdClass)#5 (2) { ["data"]=> array(0) { } ["rows"]=> int(0) }
```

Running the same query directly through PhpMyAdmin gives the desired result. `date_added` is data type `DATETIME`

Comment: write you full code as prepare() and execute()

Comment: What is the value of the variable you're binding to `:date`?

Comment: @developersaumya
Full code as requested is
    $select['from'] = date('Y-m-d 00:00:00',strtotime("2016-02-01"));
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `listings` WHERE `date_added` >= :date AND `date_added` < DATE_ADD(:date, INTERVAL 30 DAY)";
    $statement = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $statement->bindParam(":date", $select['from'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $statement->execute();

Comment: check using  $from = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime("2016-02-01"));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be a problem of your date format.
You have to use the format 'Y-m-d H:i:s' in PHP.

```
$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($yourdate));
```